# How to correctly "perfect forward" getter functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I'm creating a JSON library for C++14 and I'm trying to make use of move semantics whenever possible.

My `Value` class has several setters and getters that always try to move when possible:

```
template<class T> void setObj(T&& x)  { type = Obj; hObj.init(forward<T>(x)); } 
template<class T> void setArr(T&& x)  { type = Arr; hArr.init(forward<T>(x)); }
template<class T> void setStr(T&& x)  { type = Str; hStr.init(forward<T>(x)); }

auto& getObj() & noexcept             { assert(is<Obj>()); return hObj; }
auto& getArr() & noexcept             { assert(is<Arr>()); return hArr; }
auto& getStr() & noexcept             { assert(is<Str>()); return hStr; }
const auto& getObj() const& noexcept  { assert(is<Obj>()); return hObj; }
const auto& getArr() const& noexcept  { assert(is<Arr>()); return hArr; }
const auto& getStr() const& noexcept  { assert(is<Str>()); return hStr; }
auto getObj() && noexcept             { assert(is<Obj>()); return move(hObj); }
auto getArr() && noexcept             { assert(is<Arr>()); return move(hArr); }
auto getStr() && noexcept             { assert(is<Str>()); return move(hStr); }
```

As you can see from the code, perfect forwarding setter functions is pretty easy using templates and *universal references*.

**How can I do the same for getter functions?** I'm pretty sure I have to use a template return type but I'm not sure how to replicate ref-qualifiers and const-correctness.

Comment: The ref qualifiers feel useless to me here.

Comment: @Rapptz: That's the point of the question. I'm using the ref-qualifiers because I'm not sure how to express the same code using templates (to "perfectly-forward" return types and make sure `this` const-correctness is maintained).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Perhaps you meant to move from `hObj`, `hArr`, and `hStr` in `&&` functions?

Comment: @AndyProwl: I'm confused now - I've read pretty much everywhere (just Google for "return move c++") that it's unnecessary and sometimes harmful to call `return std::move(...)` - the object will be implicitly moved anyway. Does the presence of ref-qualifiers invalidate the previous statements and makes the use of `std::move` necessary?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: What you say is true for named objects with automatic storage duration declared inside the function (aka "local objects") or function parameters, because even though they are lvalues, the compiler can prove that you are not going to use them after, so it treats them as rvalues and moves from them. That cannot be done for data members. The standard specifies this in 12.8/32, which also redirects to 12.8/31.

Comment: Friend function templates could be a workaround: `template<typename T> friend decltype(auto) getObj(T&& p) noexcept { return forward_as<T, Obj>(hObj); }`, then call as `Value v; auto obj = getObj(v);` or `auto obj = getObj(Value());`

Comment: Btw, since your `setX` functions return `void`, I think you can mark them as `&` (lvalue-ref-qualified).

Comment: Oops, there's a typo in my comment above: `return forward_as<T, Obj>(p.hObj);`

Comment: higher order macros could also be used to duplicate functions. http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/

Comment: Allowing the implicit object parameter to be templatized could be an interesting language extension; though only class templates really benefit from it. Something like `template<typename T> decltype(auto) getObj(this T&& p) { return forward_as<T, Obj>(p.hObj); }`

Comment: It seems odd that one overload has a reference return type and another doesn't. I'd return an lvalue from the lvalue overload and an xvalue from the rvalue overload; that way it's consistent. It's up to the caller to consume that, e.g. `auto x = std::move(json).getObj()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't template on ref qualifiers and member constness, the sad answer is that you can't. You have to write them out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not like C++ templates but it does the job.

```
    #define GETTERS(V) \
            V(Obj) \
            V(Arr) \
            V(Str)

    #define VISIT(X) \
            auto &get ## X() & noexcept { assert(is<X>()); return h ## Obj; } \
            const auto &get ## X() const& noexcept { assert(is<X>()); return h ## Obj; } \
            auto &get ## X() && noexcept { assert(is<X>()); return std::move(h ## Obj); }


    GETTERS(VISIT)
```